# accessing function properties from one of its prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am sure that I misunderstand how i can access function properties from one of its prototypes .
i may got -10 because of this question , but I truly need help in understanding why it always returns **undefined**

[here is a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553856/accessing-properties-from-prototype-functions)

```js
function lookup() {
  if (!(this instanceof lookup)) {
    return new lookup();
  }
  this.url = "/administration/lookups";
};
        
lookup.prototype.partial_create = () => {
  alert(this.url);
};
        
var lookup1 = function(){
  this.url = "/administration/lookups";
}
        
lookup1.prototype.makealert = ()=>{
  alert(this.url);
}
        
$(()=>{
  new lookup().partial_create();
  new lookup1().makealert();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Calls to `=>` functions do not establish a value for `this`. Your functions should be traditional functions (declared with `function`).

Comment: @Pointy thank you sir you helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you've defined both the prototype methods as [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) - which behave [differently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this) from other functions with regard to the `this` keyword. (This indeed is the main point of using arrow functions in the first place - but they are misplaced here.) In particular (as you can read at the above link), arrow functions use the `this` of their enclosing scope - which here is the global scope. So `this` does not refer to your instance of `lookup`, but to the global object - hence `this.url` is just the global variable `url`, which (since you haven't defined such a variable) is `undefined`.

To show the difference, run the below snippet - which is identical to yours with the arrow functions replaced by "regular" `function` declarations. This now works as you presumably intend:

```js
function lookup() {
  if (!(this instanceof lookup)) {
    return new lookup();
  }
  this.url = "/administration/lookups";
};
        
lookup.prototype.partial_create = function() {
  alert(this.url);
};
        
var lookup1 = function(){
  this.url = "/administration/lookups";
}
        
lookup1.prototype.makealert = function() {
  alert(this.url);
}
        
$(()=>{
  new lookup().partial_create();
  new lookup1().makealert();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation . 
i did not know that there is a functional difference between the writing a function classical VS modern version